# Find a explicit formula for $f(x)$ where $\phi(t)=\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_x^1 t^2f(t)dt+\frac{x^{16}}{8}+\frac{x^{18}}{9}+C$

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

There exists a function $f$ wich is continuous for all $x\in R$, and satisfies the next equation:

$$\phi(t)=\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_x^1 t^2f(t)dt+\frac{x^{16}}{8}+\frac{x^{18}}{9}+C$$

Where $C$ is a constant. Now, find the explicit formula for $f(x)$ and find the value of the constant $C$.

So first, if we need to find the explicit formula for $f(x)$, we have the antiderivative of $\phi(t)$, such that $F'(x)=f(x)$, so if we differentiate the formula, we have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_x^1 t^2f(t)dt+\frac{x^{16}}{8}+\frac{x^{18}}{9}+C\right)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_x^1 t^2f(t)dt\right)+2x^{15}+2x^{17}$$

Now, for that integral I'm not pretty sure if I did it well: Let $g(t)=\int_x^1 t^2f(t)dt$, and for it to be possible to apply the first theorem, we change as $g(t)=-\int_1^x t^2f(t)dt$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\int_1^x t^2f(t)dt\right)$$
And because of the first fundamental theorem:  $g'(x)=f(1)-x^2f(x)$

So far we got: $$f(x)=f(1)-x^2f(x)+2x^{15}+2x^{17}$$

Until know, I'm lost. Is this correct?

Comment: What happened to your negative? And why is $f(1)$ there?

Comment: Because, for the $f(1)=x^2f(x)=f(1)$?

Comment: Review the first fundamental theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The first fundamental theorem says

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(-\int_1^x t^2 f(t) dt\right) = -x^2 f(x)$$

You then get
$$f(x) = -x^2f(x) +2x^{15} +2x^{17}.$$

You can continue from there.